# Dividing all numbers in a csv by the same number

Tags: csv, awk

I have files that are in millimeters and can only be read by another program in meters. I need to convert them into meters (divide by 1000). The original file format looked something like this (for hundreds of lines):

```
1.11,2.22,3.33
2.22,3.33,4.44
```

I have tried using awk and used:

```
awk '{print ($1/1000)","($2/1000)","($3/1000)}' input > output
```

This divided the numbers but changed them from 3 columns into a jumbled mess:

```
0.00111,0.00222,.003330.00222,0.00333,0.00444
```

How can I divide the numbers but keep the 3 column format?

Comment: if your  original file has passed thru an MS-Windows system, maybe `dos2unix file` will pre-clean the data. If that works and you want to know more, search here for `[linux] dos2unix`, there will be 100+ Q/As explaining in various depth and styles. Good luck.

Comment: I used 'dos2unix' and I am still getiing a messy .csv. I also tried using @RomanPerekhrest way below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i/1000}1' OFS=',' input
```

The output(for your current exemplary input):

```
0.00111,0.00222,0.00333
0.00222,0.00333,0.00444
```

---

`-F,` - field separator

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all the fields of a line

Comment: I tried this as well and it did not solve the issue. I saw something similar to that on another forum. It looks correct when I don't export it to a new file. But once it is exported it becomes the jumbled mess again

Comment: try to open your output file in some editor(vim, nano) to see if there some "special" delimiters between lines

Comment: There were. I realized that and was coming back to comment that. Thank You